# Hudson Job creates .svn files

Tags: svn, hudson, jobs, workspace, svn-checkout

When I make a SVN Repository checkout .svn files are created on the workspace.
I have checked that these files don't exist in the repository and are created when the Hudson Job makes the checkout.

What are the .svn files? Can I remove them or avoid their creation?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Those folders are created by the svn client, to keep track of your files. With subversion prior to 1.7 there is one .svn folder by folder, after there is only one on the root.

The .svn are necessary to update/commit. If your job don't need to update the working copy, you can use export instead of checkout and you will get a new copy at each build without the .svn folder, but you will not be able to update, only to remove and export again.

Comment: Are you sure with the version? I have SVN 1.7.1. and it has one .svn folder by folder. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`.svn` files are internal files of Subversion. All subversion meta data is in this directories.

In case of Hudson Job, they are irrelevant as you do not want to commit anything. You cannot avoid crating them. You can remove them but you will find them helpful when you will start using `update` instead of `checkout` on Hudson to speed up build.